opensuse leap 15.6 with nvidia driver: update fails due to unavailable libOpenCL1
On opensuse leap 15.6 , i managed to install NVIDIA driver, everithing seemed to work fine for few days, until yesterday during the software update i received the following error:
opensuse leap 15.6 error in update : the to be installed nvidia-compute-G06-550.135-lp156.28.1.x86_64 requires 'libOpenCL1', but this requirement cannot be provided.

Does anyone know why and how can be solved the problem?

please don't use CAPS LOCKS in your title; looks like you're shouting. I'm fixing this for you. Also, I'm making the title a bit more descriptive.

I've solved.
After disabling secure boot and reinstalling the Nvidia drivers , everything went fine.
